# Find every user that changed the amount(int) of a certain type column between dates a and b

Tags: sql, sql-server

My table has 6 columns, ID, username, address, date, type and amount.

I want to find every user that changed the amount(int) of a certain type column between dates a and b. I need the exact difference if it's negative it must display a negative number. The problem I am facing is that there is no unique identifier in the database(there are instances where everything but the amount is the same). ID is useless since it's just an autoincrement.

I wrote this statement:

```
SELECT a.Username, a.Address, a.diff, a.Type 
FROM (
      SELECT Username, Address, Type, MAX(Amount)-MIN(amount)AS diff 
      FROM dbo.data 
      WHERE Date='date1' OR Date='date2'  
      GROUP BY Username, Address, Type 
      HAVING MAX(amount) - MIN(amount) > 0
     ) a 
ORDER BY diff;
```

The problem with this statement are:

1. this diff is only positive numbers and
2. if the same date has the same user with a different amount of the same type it will output that difference and I only want to see if there was a difference between the dates.

I know this database is badly designed but this is how this company has it. I appreciate any input.

SAMPLE DATA:

```
    ID  USERNAME   ADDRESS   TYPE   AMOUNT    DATE
    0   JOHN       street1   NKK    200       2022-05-22
    1   ALEX       street3   NKK    400       2022-05-22
    2   MIKE       street2   MKK    400       2022-05-22
    3   MIKE       street2   MKK    300       2022-05-22
    4   MIKE       street2   MLB    500       2022-05-22
    5   JAKE       street3   MLB    499       2022-05-22
    6   JOHN       street1   NKK    100       2022-05-23
    7   ALEX       street3   NKK    400       2022-05-23
    8   MIKE       street2   MKK    500       2022-05-23
    9   MIKE       street2   MKK    300       2022-05-23
   10   MIKE       street2   MLB    600       2022-05-23
   11   JAKE       street3   NKK    499       2022-05-23
```

OUTPUT:

```
USERNAME STREET   TYPE   DIFF
JOHN     street1  NKK    -100
MIKE     street2  MKK    100
MIKE     street2  MLB    100
JAKE     street3  MLB    -499
JAKE     street3  NKK    499
```

Comment: Your issue is hard do understand without sample data and expected outcome as tables. Please add this, this will make things much more clear.

Comment: Do you really need grouping here? Have you tried self join?

Comment: I wanted to try join but i dont see a way how to achive my result with it.

Comment: @KristianBabic How to decide the logic in case if Username is 'MIKE' and type is 'MKK'?

Comment: Well that is the problem, i doubt there is a 100% solution but if i can at least get sometihng close to it. Maybe if date1 has the exact same row as date2 you exclude it.

Comment: The query's output will always be positive numbers as you are grouping and filtering the result set where the difference is greater than 0. If you do so, you wont be able to get the negative differences. For the second problem in the query, If you want to bring in the data between specific dates then use BETWEEN operator instead of OR or AND. You might get the results if you make the changes to the query. good luck!

Comment: `HAVING MIN(CASE WHEN Date = 'date1' THEN amount END) - MIN(CASE WHEN Date = 'date2' THEN amount END) <> 0` maybe?

Comment: Yes and no the result is always positive because i have no destinction between one dates amount and anothers so its always max - min (aka positive number). I dont want data between a date i want the diffrence between the amount of one date and another.

Comment: @Charlieface your code works well i will see how it handles duplicates. I did run into a problmem since it seems like if a user all of his amount of a certain type. He is not present in the date. I will need to handle such edge cases so if a user is in the new date the diff is his new amount. And if he is not in the new date but is in the old date his diff is negative his previous amount.

Comment: Provide sample data showing these edge cases, and expected results, will see what we can do

Comment: I have provided a sample edge case in the question where JAKE was not in the previous date. But i would like the diffrence to be shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to conditionally aggregate within your two dates:

```
with amounts as (
  select *, 
    Sum(case when DATE='20220523' then AMOUNT end) over(partition by USERNAME,ADDRESS,TYPE) 
    - Sum(case when DATE='20220522' then AMOUNT end) over(partition by USERNAME,ADDRESS,TYPE) as Diff
  from data
  where DATE in ('20220522','20220523')
)
select distinct USERNAME, ADDRESS, TYPE, Diff
from amounts
where Diff != 0;
```

[image]

See [demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=110109ccb64cd200d0fac4fb5bdb36b7)

Comment: This seems to work well. I have discovered an edge case where if a user isnt in the new date he lost all his amount of a certain type and the same if he isnt in the old date but is in the new date he has recived a amount of a certain type. Ill probbably just make seperate SELECT statements to handle those. Thank you for your help.